# Ellipses in the middle of a paragraph?

Tags: creative-writing, formatting, punctuation

```
Words words words. ...Words words words words.
```

Would having an ellipses right after a period like this be correct? If not, how would I incorporate them in? Would it be more like this?:

```
Words words words... Words words words words.
```

I feel like if it were formatted like above, it would feel like there's more emphasis on the pause being at the end of the first sentence, rather than the beginning of the second one like I want it to. Idk, what do you think?

Comment: Is it important to make the second line part of the same paragraph? If not strictly required, then you can do it in a new paragraph/new line to make the bifurcation between first line's full stop and second line's beginning pause.

Comment: This depends more on the context. On the other hand, until today I had not read anything formatted like the first version.

Comment: It depends on the style guide that you follow. As far as I can tell, there is no consistent agreement among all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I've always seen sentences formatted in *"Words words words... Words words words words."* version but never in the *"Words words words. ... Words words words words."* version.

If you really want to start the second sentence separately with ellipses, you could try writing it in the following format.

> Words words words.
>   ...Words words words words.

Answer (score 1):

If your question addresses the typograhic ellipsis (`…`), the correct usage might be `words … words` (at least according to [practicaltypography.com](https://practicaltypography.com/ellipses.html)). Also be aware that an ellipsis is typographically different from three periods (`...`).

But depending on the context, you could also use a dash as a *semantic ellipsis*.

One of the most famous dash-ellipses that comes to my mind is [The Marquise of O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marquise_of_O#Analysis,_discussion_of_the_rape) where the dash supposedly is the moment when the protagonist gets raped. O powerful dash :)